# Is tensorflow-gpu (=<1.14) with CUDA & cuDDN supported in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7/8 or cent os 7?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nvidia

I have cent os 7 with Nvidia 2080 super graphic & i installed the following:

1. Graphics Driver vision 430.4
2. CUDA 10.1
3. CuDNN 7.6
4. conda env python 3.7
5. tensorflow-gpu 1.14 (pip install tensorflow-gpu)

then pip instill the required libraries for the code.

but when i tried to run this code [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/image_ocr.py) i get cuDNN initialization error..

any guide or suggestions are much appreciated :-)

[image]

Comment: Please see why [pictures of exceptions are not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)

Answer (score 0):

I can not say about CentOS, since I have never installed on it but after looking at the information you provided. The error in your picture says, Cudnn can not be initialised this is most probably bc of compatibility issues. You need to follow [these](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements) requirements.
So, remove Cuda 10.1 completely and install Cuda 10. See if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a conda environment, you should install packages with conda. Try installing tensorflow-gpu with conda; it should take care of all of your dependencies aside from the NVidia driver, which you already have. Doing things in this way allows conda to take care of additional package dependencies, like the CUDA toolkit and cudnn, among other things.

Source: Installing just the 10.1 version of the CUDA toolkit (with the driver) to a system location and tensorflow-gpu in an anaconda environment, I have tensorflow-gpu 1.14 running with Cuda 10.1 on a CentOS 7 install as well as on a RHEL7 install.